# How to make all the files in a folder non-executable in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, virus, file-permissions

I'm developing an application that deals with viruses. All these viruses are in a folder, it should be possible to read them and add new ones to the folder, however I'd like to make sure that none of them can be executed.

At the moment, I've already removed the file extension but if I could make them non-executable that would be even better.

Is it possible to do this with Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt and run:

```
icacls C:\myViruses /deny "Everyone:(OI)(IO)(X)"
```

This will deny everybody the permission to execute files while users can add and delete files.

You should test this in your environment.

If you have an active virus on the system with sufficient privileges, it can undo this change, but in this case all is lost anyways.

Answer (score 1):

This can be down via group policy but, this is not by per folder but by application so it may/may not suffice as an alternative approach...

> This will not prevent users from being able to run a program through
>   the command prompt unless you also add cmd.exe to the list of
>   disallowed applications.
>
> Even if you have an .exe file of a program in the list of allowed
>   applications and also in the list of disallowed applications, then
>   users will not be able to run the .exe. Anything disallowed will
>   always override anything allowed.
>
> Renaming an .exe file will bypass the list of disallowed programs to
>   let it run anyways, but not with the list of allowed programs. If the
>   .exe file name is not on the list of allowed programs, then it can't
>   run.
>
> This does not apply to "Metro" Store apps in Windows 8.

---

> Open the all users, specific users or groups, or all users except
>   administrators Local Group Policy Editor for how you want this policy
>   applied.
>
> 2. In the left pane, click/tap on to expand User Configuration, Administrative Templates, and System.
> 3. In the right pane of System, double click/tap on Don't run specified Windows applications to edit it.
> 4. To Prevent Specified Applications from Running
>
>    A) Select (dot) Enabled, then click/tap on the Show button under Options.
>
>    B) Under Value, double click/tap in a blank line and type in the name of the EXE file (ex: cmd.exe) with file extension that you want
>      to prevent from running.
>
>    C) Repeat step 5B until you have added any other EXE files (ex: CCleaner) you want on the list of disallowed applications as well.
>      When finished, click/tap on OK.
> 5. Click/tap on OK.
> 6. If used, you may also wish to make changes to your list of allowed programs to run.
> 7. Close the Local Group Policy Editor window.

[Source](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/80605-applications-prevent-running-specified-programs.html)

Comment: Is this original or is there a link to the source of this?  I would like to default files to non-executable unless elevated by an administrator.

Comment: .... the word source is a link  @tj111?

Comment: Thanks!  It kind of blended in with the other Footer information (e.g. edited Oct 24) so I skimmed right over it.